# stm32-h743zi nucleo-144 ADC

Tags: c, adc, stm32cubeide, nucleo, stm32-hal

i have a problem with getting value from ADC on the nucleo144 board. I connected a potentiometer to the pin A0, but the ADC is stuck in the  HAL_PollForConversion function and returns 0 if the delay is set to less then HAL_MAX_DELAY.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESxfp.jpg)

Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
while(1){
  HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1); // start the adc

  HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 100); // poll for conversion

  adc_val = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1); // get the adc value

  HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1); // stop adc

  buff_len = sprintf((char*)buff,"ADC: %d\n", adc_val);
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3,buff, buff_len, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

  HAL_Delay (500); // wait for 500ms
/* USER CODE END WHILE */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */}
```

ADC config:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjZEW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the code of the `MX_ADC1_Init()` function?

I've had a similar behavior, this solved it for me:

In the `MX_ADC1_Init()` function, there was the line `hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV1` missing to set the adc clock. There was no option to select this setting in the .ioc file ;-/
Turns out that with the default value for `hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler` in the HAL, the adc won't work (see: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72249577/smt32h7-h745-h755-adc-internal-error-with-hal)).

Comment: Thank you very much! this was the problem :)

Comment: No problem. It‘s an issue with the newest CudeIDE release (1.9 or 1.10 I think). I downgraded to the previous release…