# SMT32H7 (H745/H755): ADC "internal Error" with HAL

Tags: stm32, adc, stm32cubeide, stm32-hal, stm32h7

I'm using an STM32H755 (on NUCLEO-Board) with CubeIDE and trying to set up an ADC with HAL.
Without any changes to the default ADC and clock setup, the ADC goes into "error internal" state when trying to read values. Any Ideas why?

I didn't touch any ADC or clock settings, just set the runtime context in the .ioc file.
When initialized, the ADC state goes to "Ready" (after calling `MX_ADC1_Init()`) but after starting it with `HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1)`, `HAL_ADC_GetError(&hadc1)` and `HAL_ADC_GetState(&hadc1)` read the error message "error internal" and no values can be read.

Side note: with the same setup, DAC and DMA are working fine.

Here is my code (irrelevant code cut out) :

```
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
#if defined ( __ICCARM__ ) /*!< IAR Compiler */
#pragma location=0x30000000
ETH_DMADescTypeDef  DMARxDscrTab[ETH_RX_DESC_CNT]; /* Ethernet Rx DMA Descriptors */
#pragma location=0x30000200
ETH_DMADescTypeDef  DMATxDscrTab[ETH_TX_DESC_CNT]; /* Ethernet Tx DMA Descriptors */
#pragma location=0x30000260
uint8_t Rx_Buff[ETH_RX_DESC_CNT][ETH_MAX_PACKET_SIZE]; /* Ethernet Receive Buffers */

#elif defined ( __CC_ARM )  /* MDK ARM Compiler */

__attribute__((at(0x30000000))) ETH_DMADescTypeDef  DMARxDscrTab[ETH_RX_DESC_CNT]; /* Ethernet Rx DMA Descriptors */
__attribute__((at(0x30000200))) ETH_DMADescTypeDef  DMATxDscrTab[ETH_TX_DESC_CNT]; /* Ethernet Tx DMA Descriptors */
__attribute__((at(0x30000260))) uint8_t Rx_Buff[ETH_RX_DESC_CNT][ETH_MAX_PACKET_SIZE]; /* Ethernet Receive Buffer */

#elif defined ( __GNUC__ ) /* GNU Compiler */
ETH_DMADescTypeDef DMARxDscrTab[ETH_RX_DESC_CNT] __attribute__((section(".RxDecripSection"))); /* Ethernet Rx DMA Descriptors */
ETH_DMADescTypeDef DMATxDscrTab[ETH_TX_DESC_CNT] __attribute__((section(".TxDecripSection")));   /* Ethernet Tx DMA Descriptors */
uint8_t Rx_Buff[ETH_RX_DESC_CNT][ETH_MAX_PACKET_SIZE] __attribute__((section(".RxArraySection"))); /* Ethernet Receive Buffers */
#endif

ETH_TxPacketConfig TxConfig;

 ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;

ETH_HandleTypeDef heth;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;

PCD_HandleTypeDef hpcd_USB_OTG_FS;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint64_t state = 0;
uint64_t error = 0;
uint16_t value = 0;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_ETH_Init(void);
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_USB_OTG_FS_PCD_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */
/* USER CODE BEGIN Boot_Mode_Sequence_0 */
  int32_t timeout;
/* USER CODE END Boot_Mode_Sequence_0 */

/* USER CODE BEGIN Boot_Mode_Sequence_1 */
  /* Wait until CPU2 boots and enters in stop mode or timeout*/
  timeout = 0xFFFF;
  while((__HAL_RCC_GET_FLAG(RCC_FLAG_D2CKRDY) != RESET) && (timeout-- > 0));
  if ( timeout < 0 )
  {
  Error_Handler();
  }
/* USER CODE END Boot_Mode_Sequence_1 */
  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();
/* USER CODE BEGIN Boot_Mode_Sequence_2 */
/* When system initialization is finished, Cortex-M7 will release Cortex-M4 by means of
HSEM notification */
/*HW semaphore Clock enable*/
__HAL_RCC_HSEM_CLK_ENABLE();
/*Take HSEM */
HAL_HSEM_FastTake(HSEM_ID_0);
/*Release HSEM in order to notify the CPU2(CM4)*/
HAL_HSEM_Release(HSEM_ID_0,0);
/* wait until CPU2 wakes up from stop mode */
timeout = 0xFFFF;
while((__HAL_RCC_GET_FLAG(RCC_FLAG_D2CKRDY) == RESET) && (timeout-- > 0));
if ( timeout < 0 )
{
Error_Handler();
}
/* USER CODE END Boot_Mode_Sequence_2 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ETH_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  MX_USB_OTG_FS_PCD_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_Delay(1);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */


      error = HAL_ADC_GetError(&hadc1);
      state = HAL_ADC_GetState(&hadc1);

      HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
      error = HAL_ADC_GetError(&hadc1);
      state = HAL_ADC_GetState(&hadc1);

      HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 1000);
      error = HAL_ADC_GetError(&hadc1);
      state = HAL_ADC_GetState(&hadc1);

      value = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Supply configuration update enable
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ConfigSupply(PWR_DIRECT_SMPS_SUPPLY);

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE2);

  while(!__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_VOSRDY)) {}

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_BYPASS;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 24;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLRGE = RCC_PLL1VCIRANGE_3;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLVCOSEL = RCC_PLL1VCOWIDE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLFRACN = 0;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D3PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D1PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB3CLKDivider = RCC_APB3_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_APB1_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_APB2_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB4CLKDivider = RCC_APB4_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief ADC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

  ADC_MultiModeTypeDef multimode = {0};
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */

  /** Common config
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_16B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc1.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.ConversionDataManagement = ADC_CONVERSIONDATA_DR;
  hadc1.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_PRESERVED;
  hadc1.Init.LeftBitShift = ADC_LEFTBITSHIFT_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.OversamplingMode = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure the ADC multi-mode
  */
  multimode.Mode = ADC_MODE_INDEPENDENT;
  if (HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeConfigChannel(&hadc1, &multimode) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_3;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;
  sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
  sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  sConfig.OffsetSignedSaturation = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 2 */

}
```

Comment: Did you check the register values of ADC? Any specific error flag is set?

Answer (score 2):

Found the error by myself...

In the `MX_ADC1_Init()` function, there was the line `hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV1` missing to set the adc clock. There was no option to select this setting in the .ioc file ;-/
Turns out that with the default value for `hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler` in the HAL, the adc won't work